# Are higher rated capacitors interchangeable with lower rated ones?

Tags: capacitor

I have the follow capacitors that I need to change:

[image]

I can't find these specific ones on mouser or digikey and I can't buy in such huge quantities neither if they did have. I was told that I can use the following replacement for the Pink ones:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07RBC8F62/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1BBEKKND9EC89&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RBC8F62)

```
EKZE250ELL821MJ25S, Cap Aluminum Lytic 820uF 25V 20%(10 X 25mm) Radial 5mm 2150mA 4000h 105°C Bulk (50 Items)
```

But would I be able to use these same ones to replace the smaller blue ones too? These caps are both 16V, but the uF is different only, 470 vs 270. The replacement ones are 820uF and 25V much higher numbers.

I'd like to know why would these high rated ones work aswell?

What if I purchased or extracted caps from other boards that are greater than 470uF and 16V would those also work too?

Even though they do not look the same?

Comment: Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices **must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Higher voltage ratings are probably ok, but it's not great generally to use higher capacitance values unless you know what its for. For the replacements, all you need to do is look for one that will fit on digikey that is 16V 470uF. Digikey will sell you most parts in single quantity. Try this list:

https://www.digikey.com/short/z9q7qt

Comment: When buying caps, do I just need to know the 2 main points: uF and Voltage of the cap only?

Comment: You should also get the same basic type. For example, these ones are aluminum electrolytic

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find "aluminum electrolytic" in that link. There is just an overwhelming amount of filters just for capacitors at that site. So far I only know 2 factors that I need to look for, uF and 16V. The site at digikey and number of filters is a bit overwhelming imo.

Comment: all of the ones in that link are aluminium electrolytic, 16V, 470uF. Just choose the correct size and get that one

Comment: Thats the thing. How do I tell what size it is? Do I measure it by height or width in mm?

Comment: measure all the dimensions, and then find the closest thing to those dimensions on digikey. The specifics aren't actually that important (it looks like those are through hole, but difficult to tell) as long as it fits in the space

Comment: ok, its a through hole. I'm finalizing on this one: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nichicon/UBW1C471MPD1TD/493-13148-1-ND/4333158 -- I need to extra operating temperature as the Xbox gets very hot which was the cause of it to fail in the first place. Is this capacitor ok to replace both 270uF and 470uF in my picture above?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ I would not suggest replacing the 270uF one with a 470uF one. It should be relatively straightforward to find a 270uF replacement

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the application, if the application is a power filter capacitor (used on Vcc of a component) then bigger capacitors have the same function. What is happening is we are forming an RLC filter. The LC components are formed by wires or traces. To prevent power dips sudden changes in Vcc we place a power capacitor to source power when the voltage drops (because the load changes), the value of C doesn't change the filter pole that much and bigger is usually better (but not if the ESR of the cap changes when we move to a bigger value).

When replacing power filter caps the voltage needs to be greater than that of the power rail, if you don't know what that is, then just make sure it's bigger than the cap. Make sure the ESR is equal to or smaller, and the value of the cap is equal to or bigger.

If the application is an audio filter or some other filter where the filter pole needs to be exact, then it's best to replace the cap with the exact parameters (ESR and component value) to get the same result.

So you could probably replace all caps on that board with the 470uF's (if you could figure out a way to make them fit) but not the other way around.

Comment: These caps are for an xbox one system. Supposedly these are used for regulator the power to write to the hard drive or something. The reason why it needs to replaced is it's causing data write corrupt issues. Can I use the ones I found on amazon to also replace the 270uF ones (blue)?

Comment: I don't know, what are the ESR values for the original caps?

Answer (score 3):

Higher voltage ratings are okay in and of themselves. But all things being equal, higher voltage caps have higher ESR and that *might* affect things if it's used in a switching circuit. You're probably good though unless the ESR is much higher or the circuit was borderline designed.

Answer (score 0):

Before you replace any capacitors,
you need to determine what caused them to blow in the first place.
eg.If the circuit was designed & intended to be used in the 90V -> 120 Volt range then using at 232V would explain the damage.

Comment: Note the 16 V rating on the caps in the photo.